# Evaluating definite integral of $e^{i t^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In passing Sakurai's QM book mentions that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i t^2} dt = \sqrt{i \pi}$$

This is consistent with 7.4.4 in Abramowitz and Stegun which claims for $\Re a > 0, n = 0, 1, 2, ...$

$$\int_{0}^\infty t^{2n} e^{-a t^2} dt = \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{2 a^{n+1/2}},$$

however that restriction $\Re a > 0$ isn't satisfied in this case (this is equality with zero not a greater than condition).

I noticed that the Sakurai integral can also be written

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i t^2} dt = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi i}(\textrm{erf}(\infty + i\infty)- \textrm{erf}(-\infty - i \infty)),$$

where

$$\textrm{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^z e^{t^2} dt,$$

It seems plausible that $\textrm{erf}(\infty + i\infty) = -\textrm{erf}(-\infty - i \infty)) = 1$, but I'm not sure how one would show this (such limits aren't obvious from any of the other relations I seem in A&S).

How would an definite integral like this be evaluated, and what is the origin of this $\Re a > 0$ restriction?

Comment: It's an improper integral, not an indefinite one. An indefinite integral is an antiderivative; an improper one is a definite integral with infinite bounds.

Comment: The integral as stated doesn't converge, since $|e^{it^2}| = 1$ for all real $t$. On the other hand, you can take something like $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^N e^{it^2}$, or replace the integrand with some suitable $f_n\to e^{it^2}$ and consider $\int_{\infty}^\infty f_n$, or use some suitable analytic continuation, or etc.

Comment: The integral converges as an improper Riemann integral, i.e. $\lim_{M \to -\infty, N \to +\infty} \int_{M}^N e^{it^2}\; dt$.

Comment: Fixed the indefinite -> definite typo in the last sentence of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(z)=e^{iz^2}$.  Then, $f$ is entire and by the residue theorem we have

$$\oint_C f(z)\,dz=0 \tag 1$$

for any sufficiently smooth closed contour $C$ in the complex plane. Now, suppose $C$ is comprised of the three segments; $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$, where

$(i)$ $C_1$ is the line segment on the real axis from $(0,0)$ to $(R,0)$.

$(ii)$ $C_2$ is the circular arc with radius $R$, centered at the origin, from $(R,0$ to $(R/\sqrt{2},R/\sqrt{2})$.

$(iii)$ $C_3$ is the line segment extending from $(R/\sqrt{2},R/\sqrt{2}$ to $(0,0)$.

Then, from $(1)$ we have

$$\int_0^R e^{ix^2}dx+\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{iR^2e^{i2\phi}}iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_R^0e^{i\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}t\right)^2}\,\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)dt=0 \tag 2$$

If we let $R\to \infty$, the first integral becomes $1/2$ the integral of interest, the second integral in $(2)$ vanishes, while the third integral becomes

$$-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt=-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\frac12 \sqrt{\pi}$$

Putting it all together, we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ix^2}\,dx=(1+i)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\sqrt{i\pi}}$$

since $1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}$

Comment: How do you justify the vanishing of the second integral?

Comment: The integrand has the term $e^{iR^2e^{i2\phi}}=e^{-R^2\sin 2\phi}e^{iR^2\cos 2\phi}$.  The integral of the decaying exponential tends to zero.

Comment: fyi.  I've cited your answer in a blog post covering this and some similar integrals: http://peeterjoot.com/2015/09/10/generalized-gaussian-integrals/

Comment: @PeeterJoot Wow!  Thank you.  I am honored by your referencing this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather claim that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{it^2}\,dt=(1+i)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.
$$
Note that
$$
e^{it^2}=\cos(t^2)+i\sin(t^2),
$$
so this really follows from the [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cos(t^2)\,dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(t^2)\,dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.
$$

**Edit**
Since
$$
(1+i)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\sqrt{(\pi i)},
$$
I agree with Sakurai. I first thought that the $i$ was outside the square root in your question.

Comment: I've reordered \pi i -> i \pi for clarity in my question.